# Generating slightly curved arrows in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, style, flow

In Geometry Generator in Symbology in Layer Properties, the following expression *works*, but the result is not satisfactory due to the middle point fixed coefficient 1,1:

```py
make_line (
     start_point(make_point("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude")), 
     translate(centroid($geometry), 1, 1), 
     end_point(make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude")))
```

Using the **`$length`** function as below **doesn't work**. Why no lines are displayed?

```py
make_line (
     start_point(make_point("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude")), 
     translate(centroid($geometry), $length, $length),
     end_point(make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude")))
```

Using the **`length()`** function as below works, but while some lines are displayed OK (e.g. India -> Bangladesh), some are way too curvy (e.g. Bangladesh -> India). How can I make all of them just slightly curved like the India -> Bangladesh one?

```py
make_line(
     start_point(make_point("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude")), 
     translate(centroid($geometry), 
     length(
           make_line(
                make_point("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude"), 
                make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude")
           )
     )/5000000,
     length((
           make_line(
                make_point ("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude"), 
                make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude")
                )
     ))/5000000), 
     end_point(make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude"))
)
```

QGIS version: 3.4.6

[image: example]

Comment: A manual work around would be to adjust them using node select. I use that approach to do flow maps....and applaud you for having a solution which gets *most* of the lines curved programmatically!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this expression, details in comments :

```sql
-- create a start point variable
with_variable(
    'start_point', -- name
    make_point("Origin Longitude", "Origin Latitude"), -- expression for start point

-- create an end point variable
with_variable(
    'end_point', -- name
    make_point("Dest Longitude", "Dest Latitude"), -- expression for end point

-- create a base line (start to end) variable
with_variable(
    'base_line', -- name
    make_line(
        @start_point, -- call start point variable
        @end_point -- call end point variable
    ), -- expression for base line

    -- expression for create the arrow
    -- create a line with 3 points : start point, offset centroid and end point
    make_line(
        @start_point,
        centroid(
            offset_curve(
                @base_line,
                -- 10 is curve coefficient, adjust-it
                -- a bigger number (e.g. 15) flatten the curve
                -- a lower number (e.g. 5) round the curve
                length(@base_line) / 10
            )
        ),
        @end_point
    )
)))
```

Go to the layer properties > symbology > choose the Geometry Generator for symbol type > choose Polyline / Multi-Polyline as Geometry Type and paste the code above.